# read only the first word with sscanf from a string?

Tags: c

I have a string like this :

```
char cstr[] = "i 176064 Patterson Denise 8.58 11 DEN 15788 ";
```

and i want to get only the fist word 'i' with sscanf

```
int main()
{   char cstr[] = "i 176064 Patterson Denise 8.58 11 DEN 15788 ";
    char option[20];
    sscanf(cstr, "%s",option);


}
```

what i have to do to ignore the rest of the string?

Comment: could you only use option[0] later?

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use  `sscanf` for this? (Also why is this tagged as both C++ and C?)

Comment: @UnholySheep I already kicked them from the c++ realm, where it should be concise and easy.

Comment: Looks like you want `strtok`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/.

Comment: your code looks correct and should work. What's the problem? (small improvement: do `sscanf(cstr, "%19s",option);` to avoid buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything, since the `scanf` functions automatically ignore any trailing characters.